# Lua: attempt to index local '' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

Please help: I am attempting to index local `firstClipArr` (a `nil` value) but I cannot figure out how to solve it for the life of me. Here's the code:

```
function updateRemoteAmmo( ammoTable )
if not client or getElementData(client,"loggedin") ~= 1 then
    return
end
local items = getItems( client )
local weaponCheck = { }
for _, itemCheck in ipairs( items ) do
    if (itemCheck[1] == 115) then -- Weapon item
        local weaponItemDetails = explode(':', itemCheck[2])
        local weaponAmmoCountValid = 0
        local firstClip = 0
        local firstClipInventorySlot = 0
        local firstClipArr = nil


        for itemCheckBulletsSlot, itemCheckBullets in ipairs( items ) do
            if (itemCheckBullets[1] == 116) then 
                local weaponBulletDetails = explode(':', itemCheckBullets[2])
                if tonumber(weaponBulletDetails[1]) == tonumber(weaponItemDetails[1]) then
                    if (firstClip == 0 and tonumber(weaponBulletDetails[2]) > 0) then
                        firstClip =  tonumber(weaponBulletDetails[2])
                        firstClipInventorySlot = itemCheckBulletsSlot
                        firstClipArr = weaponBulletDetails
                    end

                    weaponAmmoCountValid = weaponAmmoCountValid + weaponBulletDetails[2]
                end
            end
        end


        local weaponSyncPacket = false
        for _, tableValue in ipairs(ammoTable) do

            if tonumber(tableValue[1]) == tonumber(weaponItemDetails[1]) then

                weaponSyncPacket = tableValue
            end
        end

        if not weaponSyncPacket then

            return
        end


        local fakebullet = false
        if (getElementData(client, "cf:"..weaponItemDetails[1])) then
            fakebullet = true
            weaponAmmoCountValid = weaponAmmoCountValid + 1
        end


        if (weaponAmmoCountValid > weaponSyncPacket[2]) then -- There has been shot with this gun

            local totalBulletsShot = weaponAmmoCountValid - weaponSyncPacket[2]

            local update = updateItemValue(client, firstClipInventorySlot,firstClipArr[1] ..":"..weaponSyncPacket[3]  ..":"..  firstClipArr[3])

            if not update then
                outputDebugString("fail")
            end
            weaponAmmoCountValid = weaponAmmoCountValid - totalBulletsShot
        end

        table.insert(weaponCheck, {weaponItemDetails[1], weaponAmmoCountValid, fakebullet} )
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack! As for why you're getting the `nil` value, you never define `firstClipArr` except for the `local`, in which you explicitly define it as `nil`. It seems you're missing some code if you're meant to define `firstClipArr` with somethng other than `nil`.

Comment: Changed indentation from tabs to spaces, to make things clearer.

Comment: You already defined `local firstClipArr = nil` and never assigned it to anything else, so, you can't index it. Maybe you forgot something there

Comment: @RPMTA Please add the code directly to your post rather than putting it into a comment. It is difficult to read in the comment itself.

Comment: Sorry, bad english, edited

Comment: I would assume that `itemCheckBullets[1] == 116` never matches, did you really intend to iterate over the same table (`items`) in the inner `for` loop?

Comment: dualed, sorry, I do not understand you... Error line: local update = updateItemValue(client, firstClipInventorySlot,firstClipArr[1] ..":"..weaponSyncPacket[3]  ..":"..  firstClipArr[3])

Comment: @RPMTA At line 13, you have set "firstClipArr" to nil. It is never set anywhere else. That is why you are getting an error.

Comment: Related to solving `nil` problems in general. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174233/is-there-a-fix-for-nil-value-for-local-user/58203508#58203508