# is there a fix for Nil value for local user

Tags: lua

This is for a phone script ive been working on and im trying to update some code but I have been getting a single error.

```
Error @phone/server.lua:37: attempt to index a nil value (local 'user')
 ref (@phone/server.lua:37)
 handler (@framework/server/main.lua:242)
 getNumberPhone (@phone/server.lua:36)
 handler (@phone/server.lua:268)
```

I tried the one way I was shown here before with no luck.

line 37

```
function getNumberPhone(source, n)
    local n = 0 
    TriggerEvent('f:getPlayer', source, function(user)
        n = user.getPhoneNumber()
    end)
    return n
end
```

line 242

```
AddEventHandler("f:getPlayer", function(user, cb)
    if not cb then return end
    if(Users)then
        if(Users[user])then
            cb(Users[user])
        else
            cb(nil)
        end
    else
        cb(nil)
    end
end)
```

line 36

```
function getNumberPhone(source, n)
    local n = 0 
    TriggerEvent('f:getPlayer', source, function(user)
        n = user.getPhoneNumber()
    end)
    return n
end
```

line 286

```
RegisterServerEvent('gcPhone:allUpdate')
AddEventHandler('gcPhone:allUpdate', function()
    local source = source
    local identifier = GetPlayerIdentifiers(source)[1]
    TriggerClientEvent("gcPhone:myPhoneNumber", source, getNumberPhone(source))
    TriggerClientEvent("gcPhone:allMessage", source, getMessages(identifier,source))
    TriggerClientEvent("gcPhone:contactList", source, getContacts(identifier))  
end)
```

Comment: @joehinkle11 here it is!

Comment: Should `getNumberPhone` be invoked on client or on server?

Comment: Should be called on the server after the player joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explaining the Error

In Lua, this is one of the most common errors you will run into, so it is very important for you to know how to solve it.

The error: `attempt to index a nil value`

To understand what this error means, you only need to understand these concepts.

- In Lua, only tables can be indexed (i.e. `myTable[myIndex]`)
- In Lua, if a variable evaluates to `nil`, then attempting to index it as if it were a table throws an error

So it should be a little easier to understand the error you received. A more explicit way to describe this error would be something like "the Lua interpreter attempted to index your variable `user` on line 37 but `user` evaluated to `nil`."

### Your Specific Case

On line 242 you are calling a callback and passing `nil`

```
cb(nil)
```

This callback sends this `nil` value to line 37 as the `user` parameter

```
TriggerEvent('f:getPlayer', source, function(user)
    n = user.getPhoneNumber()
end)
```

So when you try to run `user.getPhoneNumber()` you are actually running `nil.getPhoneNumber()`, which throws the error you saw.

### Ways to fix this type of error

1) Whenever you are working with a variable that could be `nil`, create an if statement checking to see if it is `nil` before proceeding.

2) Make sure you never set that variable to `nil`.

### Ways to fix your specific error

1) On line 36, create this if statement

```
TriggerEvent('f:getPlayer', source, function(user)
    if user ~= nil then
        n = user.getPhoneNumber()
    end
end)
```

Or do a similar nil check like this

```
TriggerEvent('f:getPlayer', source, function(user)
    if user then
        n = user.getPhoneNumber()
    end
end)
```

2) Always pass a user in your callback. For example, on line 242 and elsewhere, pass an actual user object.

```
cb(Users[someUser])
```

Comment: You are amazing @joehinkle I fixed this one and fixed the other 3 nils I had. Thank you for such a clear explanation on this. The ones I have found on google where kinda sloppy.

Comment: @Nix Great! I was actually trying to find an article to explain the concept and couldn't find any. This is a major annoyance in Lua for me. This problem is really well solved in Swift with optionals. Not sure if you've done any Swift, but you would love optionals after dealing with Lua errors like this.